# Leiningen, is there something like mvn help:effective-pom?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

In Leiningen, is there something like Mavens "mvn help:effective-pom"?

I want to know which dependencies are imported as transitive deps of my deps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but with Lein 2 you can run `lein deps :tree` to see a dependency tree.

Answer (score 3):

uvtc response is right, but remember that you can always do "lein pom" to generate a pom and then work with whatever maven tool/plugin you want

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for an answer to the same question when I saw this page. In the meanwhile, I have discovered

```
lein pprint
```

which does something very similar to help:effective-pom